# Is there a javascript library to reproject a geojson so that mapbox gl will render it looking like 'Plate-Carrée'?

Tags: projection, mapbox-gl-js

I'm building a web application using Angular and mapbox-gl-js as map library.
The map tiles are projected using EPSG:4326 Plate-Carrée and the dataset is GeoJson (WGS84). 
Since mapbox supports only web mercator projection, the data is not displayed in the correct position on map. 
Any suggestions how to reproject the dataset so mapbox is able to display the data in the correct location?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at: https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/#geoEquirectangular ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have some raster tiles which are "projected" (well, not really) in EPSG:4326, and you would like to display them in Mapbox-GL-JS. You also have another dataset, in GeoJSON, also provided in EPSG:4326, which you would like to overlay.

As you note, Mapbox-GL-JS only supports the EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator) projection. It projects datasets (but not raster tiles) from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 in order to display them.

Your good options are:

- Find a different basemap in Web Mercator
- Find a web service which can reproject the tiles you have on the fly

Maybe there's some way where you could let Mapbox-GL-JS think it's displaying your tiles in EPSG:3857, then somehow adjust the coordinates of your overlaid dataset so that when they're reprojected from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 they end up in the right positions. But I can't think how to achieve that.

You could try asking at gis.stackexchange.com.